# Spring Security Plugin, properties not found

Tags: grails, plugins, properties, spring-security

I upgraded from Grails 2.2.1 to 2.2.2, but now when I run, the default properties for the spring security core plugin cannot be found. You can see from this screen shot that the properties aren't being found. 
[image: Default spring security login dialog.]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I upgraded to version 2.2.3 of grails as Burt suggested. However, now I get the following:

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/movies
| Error 2013-06-25 06:06:11,580 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR [/movies].[gsp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/movies] threw exception
Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-06-25 06:06:12,885 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR [/movies].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/movies] threw exception
Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    Line | Method
->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64820', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing a bug in Grails 2.2.2, but it's fixed in 2.2.3 which will be released this week. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10058