# Spring Security UI plugin for Grails creates neither spring-security-ui.css nor i18n files

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Eclipse STS. I executed:

- grails s2-quickstart seguridad Usuario Rol Requestmap
- grails s2ui-override auth
- grails s2ui-override layout

Domain, controller and view files for login where created:

- layout/springSecurityUI.gsp
- login/auth.gsp (has been overwritten after grails s2ui-override auth)
- ...

But these files have not been created:

- web-app/css/spring-security-ui.css
- grails-app/i18n/messages.spring-security-ui.properties

This is a screenshot of the login result:

[image: screenshot login form]

Should I do something else to create the css file so it look beautiful?

Comment: Question might be duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204260/spring-security-plugin-properties-not-found) and this [issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10058).

Comment: OK @dmahapatro . I'm going to try with the new Grails 2.2.3, and I'm tell you back

Comment: @dmahapatro with Grails 2.2.3 it does not create these files either. run-app fails also with the next error: `An internal error occurred during: "Launching grails233prototipo (run-app)".
invalid version "1.1.3-sources": non-numeric "3-sources"`
Any suggestion? Maybe to copy the files that should be created from anywhere else?

Comment: I changed the eclipse STS IDE. Now, with Grails 2.2.3 and Eclipse Kepler 4.3 with the [nightly Grails plugin](http://www.springsource.org/STS-installation-instructions) I can run the web application. It does not generate those files yet. But the i18n traslation is gotten from the plugin itself correctly. It does not generate the css file either. But I guess it get some css from the JQueryUI plugin somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the files from the directory you need, from the version you need

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/tree/master/grails-app/assets/stylesheets

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/tree/master/grails-app/i18n